# What force is responsible for anti-gravity?

Tags: gravity

I've seen several video which claims that is [anti-gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-gravity). I am sure at least one of them, use a kind of electricity to lift an object! (triangle lifter), I would guess electricity lift that object by air. But what is the equation?, I have no idea.

Comment: I don't think this is really answerable unless you provide a link to one of the videos you're referring to.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16474/2751

Comment: Suggestion to the question (v3): Instead of 'anti-gravity', a better word to describe the videos is ['levitation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levitation). Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-gravity): _[Anti-gravity] does not refer to the lack of weight under gravity experienced in free fall or orbit, or to balancing the force of gravity with some other force, such as electromagnetism or aerodynamic lift._

Comment: The triangle lifter you're referring to works by ionizing air and forcing it downward, producing lift. The Mythbusters crew tested it in a vacuum and it didn't work, so it's clearly not anti-gravity. It's just a highly inefficient way of obtaining lift.

Comment: Gravity?  Really, a force involved with (?:anti-)?gravity is gravity.  You need to be more explicit with your question.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the electromagnetic force, which is governed by Maxwell's Equations. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) for the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

If anti-gravity is the absence of gravity contribution to the forces, then by definition no force is responsible of this absence. Either you go very far from any source of gravitational attraction, or you revolutionize modern physics.

If anti-gravity is a counter-acting force which cancels out gravity, then probably [electromagnetic force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), with the possible use of [superconducting magnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity). Most videos that claim anti-gravity will use something like that.

If anti-gravity is [the effect of gravity on anti-matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter), then nobody knows completely how this works.