# Could a super conductor actually be used to repel gravity?

Tags: superconductivity

I've always been interested in anti-gravity and how you could do it. I know that it would make space travel easier because less fuel would be required, but is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16474/.  See also http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/952. For levitation, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/levitation

Answer (score 0):

Diamagnetic materials (including superconductors) experience a force in a magnetic field gradient, in the direction of decreasing field.  If the force is in the opposite direction of the force of gravity this is referred to as [levitation](http://www.ru.nl/hfml/research/levitation/diamagnetic/).

Even a [live frog](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1vyB-O5i6E) has been levitated

However, this does not directly lead to improved spaced travel.  You need energy to make the magnetic field.